# Convert Symfony Query to Laravel 6.x Eloquent Query

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, symfony-3.4, laravel-6.2

I am currently migrating a Symfony 3.4 site to Laravel 6.x and I am looking for the right way to convert this query to a Laravel Eloquent query.

Here is the Symfony Query

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('up');
 $qb->select('COUNT(up.id)');
 $qb->leftJoin('up.workout', 'w')
        ->leftJoin('up.user', 'u')
        ->where('up.parent IS NULL AND up.deleted = false')
        ->andWhere('up.status != \'Just started\' OR up.status is NULL')
        ->andWhere('w.workoutType = \'Normal\' AND u.deleted = false')
        // Long Cardio, Long Cardio (Burn) and Long Cardio (Hardcore)
        ->andWhere('up.completed = true OR (up.completed_cardio_shred = true AND ((w.level = \'Long Cardio\') OR (w.level = \'Long Cardio (Burn)\') OR (w.level = \'Long Cardio (Hardcore)\')))');
  $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

This is what I produced using the Laravel 6.x DB Query

```
 $userProgressTable = DB::table('user_progress');
    $userProgressTable->select('id');
    $userProgressTable->leftJoin('fos_user', 'fos_user.id', '=', 'user_progress.user_id');
    $userProgressTable->leftJoin('workout', 'workout.id', '=', 'user_progress.workout_id');
    $userProgressTable->whereRaw('user_progress.parent_id IS NULL');
    $userProgressTable->where('user_progress.deleted', '=', false);
    $userProgressTable->whereRaw('user_progress status <> \'Just started\' OR user_progress.status IS NULL');
    $userProgressTable->where('workout.workout_type', '=', 'Normal');
    $userProgressTable->where('user.deleted', '=', false);
    $userProgressTable->whereRaw('user_progress.completed = true OR (user_progress.completed_cardio_shred = true AND ((workout.level = \'Long Cardio\') OR (workout.level = \'Long Cardio (Burn)\') OR (workout.level = \'Long Cardio (Hardcore)\'))');
    $userProgressTable->where('user_progress.user_id', '=', $user->id);
    return $userProgressTable->count();
```

My question is, What would the above query look like if I were to use  a Eloquent Model/Query way?

Comment: You could do it the Eloquent way with Eloquent relationships. https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships

Comment: What you (and every user of frameworks) need is to stop re-inventing the wheel and use proper SQL. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you'd have to have the model classes themselves, with any relations set up correctly. From the code you shared, I see three separate models. Generally you'd want one model per table, but that dependents on the table a bit too. You don't need one for a pivot table for example (but you could have one).

```
class UserProgress extends Eloquent
{
    ...
}

class FosUser extends Eloquent
{
    ...
}

class workout extends Eloquent
{
    ...
}
```

You can name the classes anything you like, they don't have to match the table name (see the documentation for details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

Then add your relationships to each model that needs them (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships), then you can start the query. It could look something like this:

```
$result = UserProgress::join('fos_user', 'fos_user.id', '=', 'user_progress.user_id')
    ->join('workout', 'workout.id', '=', 'user_progress.workout_id')
    ->whereRaw('...')
    ...
    ->where('user_progress.user_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->get(); // this returns a Collection object

return $result->count(); // This is a Collection method
```

This is just an example, and there's a lot of ways you can structure your where clauses (`where('user_id', '=', $user.id)` vs `whereUserId($user.id)`, etc.) but should be enough to get you started.

Also, for this particular query, you really only need the first model, but it's likely you'll end up using the models for the other two tables eventually.